# How to add arm64 in third party framework (IOTCamera.framework)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am using IOT Camera library.its working on simulator and device.but when I make the build I am getting error

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
> "*OBJC_CLASS*$_Camera", referenced from:
> objc-class-ref in PVPetLiveShowController.o
> (maybe you meant: *OBJC_CLASS*$_CameraShowGLView, *OBJC_CLASS*$_Cameras )
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).

how can I fix the issue.i have already Add 64,7s,7,i386.Please suggest me how to Add Arms64 add in our third Party library IOTCamera.framework.may be the problem is IOTCamera.framework this is not supported.

Comment: Add a link to the `IOTCamera.framework`.

Comment: Thanks Droppy

Here is the sample code IOT Framework Link.
https://github.com/Shalow/CameraMonitor_iOS